# Removed span still exists

Tags: jquery

I have a selection from dropdown and a button to add from the dropdown.

```
<select id="cbo-names">
    <option value="1">John</option>
    <option value="2">james</option>
    <option value="3">Bob</option>
    <option value="4">Mary</option>
</select>
<button onclick="add_parameter()">Add</button>
```

when the button is clicked, it will add the selected item to a div then do an ajax request

```
//code for button
function add_parameter()
{
    var new_span = '<span id="span-read-'+$('#cbo-names').val()+'" class="label label-success" data-value="'+$('#cbo-names').val()+'">';
    new_span    += $('#cbo-names').text();
    new_span    += '    <button onclick="remove_object(\'span-read-\'+$('#cbo-names').val()+'\')></button>';
    new_span    += '</span>';

    $('#div-read').html($('#div-read').html() + new_span);

    fetch_records();
}
```

example

```
<div id="div-read">
    <span id="span-read-1" data-value="1">John</span>
    <span id="span-read-2" data-value="2">James</span>
    <span id="span-read-3" data-value="3">Bob</span>
</div>
```

Now, this works fine, but once I started to remove a span from the list, the span that was already removed is still being used eventhough it no longer exists.

```
function remove_object(id)
{
    $(id).remove();

    fetch_records();
}
```

and how i read it for my ajax function

```
//ajax call
function fetch_records();
{
    var arr_names = [];
    //this part is the problem.
    $('#div-read span').each(function(index, element)
    {
        arr_names.push($(this).attr('data-value'));
        //alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
    });        

    //more ajax code
}
```

just to be sure, i even check the value by alert, it is still in there.

any help is very much appreciated.

## Note:

The code is longer than this, i made it as simple as I can, so there might be some problem/syntax error, but the real problem is the reading of the div before doing ajax request, I made sure that part is exactly the same.

## added fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ysLk6178/

Comment: If you are sure about the id passed to remove method is correct, you can try adding a timeout before calling fetch records method.

Comment: I did this, still the same.

Comment: ```.val()++``` is not valid in function ```add_parameter```. You probably wanted just one ```+```?

Comment: I did mention in my note that this is the 'shorter' version of the code, the problem is not really on the add_parameter, but the looping in the fetch_records where it reads the span inside the div

Comment: can you add a FIDDLE reflecting your issue ?

Comment: i have added the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7wmcx7L8/3/),

I have updated the markup to pass object rather than id of span

`onclick="remove_object(this)"`

below is updated code of `add_parameter` function

```
function add_parameter() {

    var new_span = '<span id="span-read-' + $('#cbo-names').val() + '" class="label label-success" data-value="' + $('#cbo-names').val() + '">';
    new_span += $('#cbo-names').text();
    new_span += '<button onclick="remove_object(this)">Remove this</button>';
    new_span += '</span>';

    $('#div-read').html($('#div-read').html() + new_span);

      fetch_records();
  }
```

And then updated the `remove_object` function to work as required

```
function remove_object(obj)
 {
      $(obj).closest('span').remove();
      fetch_records();
 }
```

**Edit**

Try this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7wmcx7L8/4/) that reflect existing span ids

Hope it works for you

Comment: This fiddle works yes, but my main problem is at the fetch_record function where I am looping through the div to get the span inside

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my answer although you already accepted another answer but I had the code finished so ... :).

The main difference is in the function `add-parameter`. E.g. the event handler for `click` is not added directly but it is caught on the `div` and delegated to the `button`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#div-read').on("click", "button", function() {
        var $closesSpan = $(this).closest("span");
        remove_object($closesSpan);
    })
});

function add_parameter() {
    var spanId = "span-read-" + $('#cbo-names').val();
    var spanText = $("#cbo-names option:selected").text();
    var $newSpan = $("<span>", { "id": spanId, "class": "label label-success", "data-value": spanId, "text": spanText });
    var $newButton = $("<button>", {"text": "remove"});

    $newSpan.append($newButton);
    $('#div-read').append($newSpan);

    fetch_records();
}

function remove_object($toRemove) {
    $toRemove.remove();

    fetch_records();
}

function fetch_records() {
    var arr_names = [];

    $('#div-read span').each(function (index, element)
    {
        arr_names.push($(this).attr('data-value'));
    });       

    //more ajax code
}
```

Js-fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z7xe3ava/).